# Windows pc not detecting ESP32

Tags: microcontroller, esp32

I ran two scripts on two different ESP32 to transfer data over WiFi. Esp and the script was working perfectly fine in the beginning.

Now my ESP suddenly can not be detected when i plug it into my pc. Is it because of my script, or is the ESP just dead somehow? How can you troubleshoot this issue? I am unable to upload code onto my ESP since it is not detected.
Code is also here: https://github.com/MartinLykke/Programming-of-Robots-SDU

````
void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
     // Check WiFi connection status
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED ){ 
      distance = httpGETRequest(serverNameTemp);
      Serial.println("distance: " + distance);
      
      // save the last HTTP GET Request
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
  }
}

String httpGETRequest(const char* serverName) {
  WiFiClient client;
  HTTPClient http;
    
  // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
  http.begin(client, serverName);
  
  // Send HTTP POST request
  int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
  
  String payload = "--"; 
  
  if (httpResponseCode>0) {
    Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    payload = http.getString();
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Error code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
  // Free resources
  http.end();

  return payload;
}
```
````

Comment: Which ESP32 devices do you have? Are you using good quality cables? Does the serial port device get created when you plug it in?

Comment: ESP-32-WROVER-B. Sorry, i forgot to add that the esp worked fine this morning. So yes, the cables work. The serial port got created when i plugged it in early, but now it does not get created.

Comment: The serial port is created by a dedicated USB-UART chip which is not affected in any way by the code in the ESP32. Either your board is dead, your cable doesn't connect, or your USB port is dead.